# The set of an absolutely convergent series' all lacunary series is compact

Tags: functional-analysis

An exercise of Functional Analysis.

Complete problem is:

Let $X$ be a Banach space, in which $\sum_{n\ge 1}x_n$ is absolutely convergent, and the sum is $s$. Then, let set $E$ be the sum of **all lacunary series** of $\sum_{n\ge 1}x_n$. Prove that

1. $E$ is compact.
2. $E = s-E$
3. If $\{n|x_n\not=0\}$ is finite, $E$ is discrete ; otherwise, $E$ is perfect.

I tried to prove that every sequence in $E$ have a convergent sub-sequence, but got stuck.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: For 1, use the fact (proven through diagonal processes or Tychonov) that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is a compact metric space, seen as $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. 2. is easy. For 3, a compact space is always complete (but perhaps that wasn’t what you meant)?

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you! Yet I still have questions on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$: I know that it's compact because it's the product space of $\{0,1\}$. But the metric is the sup of $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...)$, which is not the same as $\sum_n x_n = x$. How should I use that fact on this problem? Thank you!

Comment: You’re using the metrics of uniform convergence, ie the wrong one. You need to use a metrics of *pointwise* convergence, and show that $A \longmapsto \sum_{n \in A}{x_n}$ is continuous for this metrics.

Comment: I think in 3. it should be "... otherwise, $E$ is perfect".

Comment: @Mindlack So...If I choose a metrics of pointwise convergence, which I have known one, then I just get the continuous of the map (use $f(\lim x_n) = \lim f(x_n)$). Then it's easy to show that the map is bijection, then $E$ is compact...Wow. I should think more of how to prove that map is continuous... Thank you very much!

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes you're right, I will edit it.